# Highlight row using CSS

Tags: css

The following is a class which I use to highlight a row, but it only makes changes for the  `cursor` and font, not `bgcolor` of a row.

I have also used background-color: #FFDC87; but it fails to get the desired output.

```
.highlighted {

    bgcolor: #FFDC87;
    cursor          : pointer;
    /*font-size : 50px;*/
}
```

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 11):

That's because the `bgcolor` CSS property doesn't exist. The property you're looking for is `background-color`.

If this doesn't work, there's something else that is messing with the element's `background-color`, and is blocking this from working. But we'll need a little more code to help you with that.

Comment: There's always `!important` to save the day. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#important-rules

Comment: No offense, but the OP missed the obvious `bgcolor`... IMO he shouldn't be exposed to !important just yet.

Answer (score 5):

As is clear by the other answers, it's `background-color` instead of `bgcolor`. Note that you can see if there are errors in your HTML, JS or CSS code if you're using a plug-in like [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843) or [Webdeveloper](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60) (both Firefox plug-ins). This is what Webdeveloper mentioned:

[alt text http://img191.imageshack.us/img191/7469/csserror.png](http://img191.imageshack.us/img191/7469/csserror.png)

And you'll probably also want to make the table's borders collapse, otherwise the rows in your table will have gaps in it. Here's what you could do:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
      }
      td {
        padding-right: 10px;
      }
      .highlighted {
        background-color: #ffdc87;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr class="highlighted">
        <td>1</td><td>11</td><td>111</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td><td>22</td><td>222</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="highlighted">
        <td>3</td><td>33</td><td>333</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td><td>44</td><td>444</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="highlighted">
        <td>5</td><td>55</td><td>555</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of bgcolor, the CSS rule is `background-color`. Give that a try.

Answer (score 2):

The CSS for background color is "background-color", e.g.
background-color: #FFDC87;

Try that :)